# Can you save an iMessage drawing?

Tags: messages, ios

I'm wondering if you can save a Digital Touch drawing made in iMessage on iOS10.

For example I made this drawing:

[image]

<sub>*Please do not reuse without permission*</sub>

I took a screenshot of it but it's not the best option.

Once in the messages, if I press and hold the drawing I can "Copy" it, then  paste somewhere else (for example in a Note). But the resolution seems lower.

Is there a way to keep it as an image in the best possible resolution?

Comment: "Please do not reuse without permission" Great question.

Comment: At least on Mac, through a bunch of tests, I can confirm the drawing is identified as text

Comment: @Josh I don’t understand what your last comment means? What tests?

Comment: On messages, if you right click, there is Services submenu. I created a Contextual Workflow and went through all the likely input options until I found one that makes the workflow show up in that services menu. The only one that seemed to work was the input as text. Therefore I concluded it is text being represented as a drawing.

Comment: My idea was if I could figure out where it was being stored then I could created a context menu so it could be extracted and save but unfortunately all workflows pose an error message.

Comment: @Josh oh that sounds very smart! Text or code? Isn’t the animation of the drawing being drawn saved as well? So it would be in the Messages desktop app data?

Comment: Not too sure. My guess is its something like this (keep in mind this is way over simplified): [{57,34}, {35,67}, 0.5 )], [{36,21}, {87,123},1] Which would be some animation from one point to another point in a certain amount of time. But the problem with this idea is then it would be some kind of vector image in which there would be no pixely images. But on Mac, drawings are received almost as very pixely GIF's.

Comment: Hmm. I have idea but its going to be annoying. Lets continue this in [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78812/saving-imessage-drawings).

Comment: @Josh interesting. So either gather the vector data and interpret it or find a way to display/save in highest possible res from a mac?

Comment: I replied in chat

Comment: @Josh "Page not found"

Comment: Was working before not sure what happened to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can save it. After you send the drawing, underneath the word "keep" should appear. Click on it to save the drawing.

Comment: Is there a way to save it to the roll? What's the highest resolution it can be saved in?

Answer (score 0):

I learned that once you send the digital touch message you can save them.

Go to the recipients name at top of chat and select info (the “I” icon). From there all the photographs, movies, and attachments you have sent can be selected to your phones. Hold a photo or attachment until the options "copy, delete or more" pop up. Your photos and videos will be saved in your photo album.

Comment: I sent myself [a doodle](https://imgur.com/CBwhrwA), but [it never showed up](https://imgur.com/cNqMTNL) in *Images* for that contact, nor did it show up [in *Attachments*](https://imgur.com/PIx8OZ9)